# Why am I unable to cd within a dockercontainer?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, directory

I would like to automatically execute tasks inside a docker container. The task that should be executed should be run inside a specific, mounted directory. To do this, I am using the this command:

```
docker run --rm -v /a/dir/on/my/host:/tmp some_container /bin/bash -c "cd /tmp/dir/inside/volume && echo \"$PWD\""
```

, followed by the actual task, which I omit, due to brevity.

`PWD` should give me `/tmp/dir/inside/volume`, but prints `/a/dir/on/my/host`. **Why is that?**

Answer (score 2):

`$PWD` is expanded before you run your container. Use single quotes instead of double quotes to defer expansion. Also it's simpler to use `--workdir` or `-w` instead of `cd .. &&` and subshell.

```
docker run --rm -v /a/dir/on/my/host:/tmp some_container /bin/bash -c 'cd /tmp/dir/inside/volume && echo "$PWD"'
```

or I suggest:

```
docker run --rm -v /a/dir/on/my/host:/tmp -w /tmp/dir/inside/volume /some_container pwd
```

Comment: Well that explains a lot. I did not know that `$PWD` is expanded BEFORE I execute that command. Thanks!

Comment: Try putting `echo` at the very front of the command line.  The shell will do whatever processing it was going to do and then print out the actual command it would have run.

Comment: I often do `(set -x; the command )` like `( set -x;  docker run --rm alpine sh "echo \"$PWD\"" )`

Comment: what does `set -x` do?

Comment: Prints the command prepended with `+` and a space on standard error before exeucting. [Bash reference The Set Buitlin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)